# Doctrine 1.2: Overriding Doctrine_Record::__get() from a template

Tags: doctrine, behavior, getter-setter, doctrine-1.2

I have a model class (obviously, it extends Doctrine_Record) that "acts as" a custom template.

I want to get values like this: "echo $record->virtual_field". Is there a way to override the getter method in my custom template to provide a custom response, then either pass on the request to the parent class or not?

In other words, is there a way to override Doctrine_Record::__get() from a related template?

Comment: +1 for this good question. But what exactly do yo mean by "clear the field"?

Comment: Well, I guess a better thing to say would be "If I find a vitrual_field call, don't call the parent __get()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I assume you're not talking about actual Behaviour 'actAs' Templates.

If you define a new __get() method, it will automatically override the parent's __get() method.

Now in your new __get() method, you first check if it exists in your current instance, and then the parent's.

I hacked this together (bear in mind, it's almost midnight):

```php
<?php
class bar {
public $data = array();
  public function __construct() {
    $this->data['virtual_field'] = "set in bar";
  }

  public function  __get($name) {
    if(array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
      return $this->data[$name];
    }
    return null;
  }

  public function __set($name, $value) {
    $this->data[$name] = $value;
  }
}

class foo extends bar {
public $data = array();
  public function __construct() {

  }

  public function  __get($name) {
    if(array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
      return $this->data[$name];
    }
    if (parent::__get($name))
      return parent::__get($name);

    return null;
  }

  public function __set($name, $value) {
    $this->data[$name] = $value;
  }
}

$a = new foo;
echo $a->virtual_field;
```

Now I dont know how well this works for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am talking about Doctrine behaviors, not the model classes themselves. I want to add a virtual field (like "virtual_field" in your example) to more than one model at once by putting the functionality into a template class (which is part of a behavior).

Comment: Ok. I think now I understand what you are trying to do. You want to override Doctrine_Record::__get() from a Doctrine_Template, is that right? Now, that's a tough one ;) Disregard my answr then, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

```php
class Product extends Doctrine_Record {

    //...

    public function __get($name) {
        if ($name == 'virtual_field') {
            return $this->virtual_field();
        }                                                     
        else {
            return parent::__get($name);
        }
    }


    public function virtual_field() {
        // calculate or retrieve virtual field value
        return $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to get across here? I suggest you read through the question and the accepted answer again.

Comment: Exactly what you said in an earlier comment: "Well, I guess a better thing to say would be 'If I find a vitrual_field call, don't call the parent __get()'"

Comment: Right. Then I said "I am talking about Doctrine behaviors, not the model classes themselves. I want to add a virtual field (like "virtual_field" in your example) to more than one model at once by putting the functionality into a template class (which is part of a behavior)."